# finite series of $k^2$ and $k$ for odd $k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to compute the finite sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2$$
and $$\sum_{k=1}^n k$$
for only $k$ which are odd.

I tried to go with the sum of $(2k+1)$ but I cant get far with that.

Comment: Hint:  it's relatively easy to treat the case when $n$ is even.

Comment: If you conjecture the formula for the second sum, you can easily prove it by induction.

Comment: @lulu I thought about doing the combination thing (for the series of k case) but I still cant figure it out

Comment: @Bernard Oh I see its the square of (n+1)/2. but what about the series of k^2?

Comment: It's nor exactly the square you say, but the square of $\bigl\lceil\frac n2\bigr\rceil$. As to the sum of squares, is also the sum for odd $k$s?

Answer (score 5):

Calculate each sum (including $k^2$) for *all* $k$ and then subtract the (simple) sum for *even* $k$.

Comment: Yeah I solved this one but what about series of k^2

Comment: +1 As I was typing my answer, I saw yours. Just needed to double-check for typos before posting mine.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n=2m+1$. Then compute 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} k^2 -\sum_{k=1}^m (2k)^2 = \sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} k^2 -4\sum_{k=1}^m k^2 
$$
and 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2m+1} k -\sum_{k=1}^m (2k) = \sum_{k=0}^m (2k+1) = 2\left( \sum_{k=1}^m k\right)+(m+1). 
$$

Comment: Yep.  Thanks.  Just like I said... (+1).

Comment: for n = 3 that's not working or am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielSegal For $n=3$, then $m=1$. I checked all the equalities above and they work.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k+1)^2=4\sum_{k=1}^n k^2+4\sum_{k=1}^n k-\sum_{k=1}^n 1=2\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}-2n(n+1)-n$$

In the second case, we have:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n 2k+1=2\sum_{k=1}^n k-\sum_{k=1}^n 1=n(n+1)+n$$

Comment: but in the first case you compute also (2n+1)^2 in